# How to build the following dictionary, from a list using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Hello I have the following data:

```
hello this is a car
<hamburguer>this car is very good<\hamburguer>I want to fill this rules 
this pencil is red and very good, the movie was very fine
<red>the color is blue and green<\red>
<blue>your favorite color is the yellow<\blue>you want this<red>my smartphone is very expensive<\red>
```

from this data I got a list as follows:

```
lines = ['hello this is a car','<hamburguer>this car is very good<\hamburguer>I want to fill this rules','this pencil is red and very good, the movie was very fine','<red>the color is blue and green<\red>','<blue>your favorite color is the yellow<\blue>you want this<red>my smartphone is very expensive<\red>']
```

I would like to build the following dictionary from this list, this is my expected output:

```
dict_tags = {<hamburguer>:['this car is very good'],<red>:['the color is blue and green','my smartphone is very expensive'],<blue>:['your favorite color is the yellow']}
```

Since I dont have any idea of how to proceed, I tried the following:

```
for line in lines:
    pattern = re.search(r"(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)",line)
    if pattern:
        list_tags.append(pattern.group())
```

However the issue is that I just got:

```
['this car is very good', 'the color is blue and green', 'your favorite color is the yellow<\x08lue>you want this<red>my smartphone is very expensive']
```

So I need support to build the dictionary that I need, Thanks for the support, I need the data that is between the tags, for instance:

```
<red>the color is blue and green<\red>
```

I need to extract the tag:

```
<red>
```

and the information:

```
the color is blue and green
```

Comment: I hope you are not trying to parse XML/HTML with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `re.finditer`.

**Regex**: [`<([^>]+)>([^>]+)<\\\1>`](https://regex101.com/r/ldvGCw/2)

```
lst = {}
for item in re.finditer(r'<([^>]+)>([^>]+)<\\\1>', input):
    lst.setdefault('<%s>' % item.group(1),[]).append(item.group(2))
```

Output:

```
{'<red>': ['the color is blue and green', 'my smartphone is very expensive'], '<blue>': ['your favorite color is the yellow'], '<hamburguer>': ['this car is very good']}
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/YSazOz)

Answer (score 2):

With **`re.findall()`** function and **`collections.defaultdict`** object:

```
import re, collections

s = '''hello this is a car
<hamburguer>this car is very good<\\hamburguer>I want to fill this rules 
this pencil is red and very good, the movie was very fine
<red>the color is blue and green<\\red>
<blue>your favorite color is the yellow<\\blue>you want this<red>my smartphone is very expensive<\\red>'''

tags_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
tags = re.findall(r'<([^>]+)>([^<>]+)(<\\\1>)', s)    # find all tags

for tag_open, value, tag_close in tags:
  tags_dict[tag_open].append(value)    # accumulate values for the same tag

print(dict(tags_dict))
```

The output:

```
{'hamburguer': ['this car is very good'], 'red': ['the color is blue and green', 'my smartphone is very expensive'], 'blue': ['your favorite color is the yellow']}
```

Comment: I'd add that it is important that OP uses raw string as there are instances of `\b` and `\r` throughout the strings. `\b` in `<\blue>` definitely causes an issue (`<\x08lue>` in OPs output)